# Ignore not well-formed UTF-16

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-16

I am creating a flutter chat application, and it's possible to have not well-formed UTF-16 characters in the `Text`

How can I simply find and replace all not well-formed UTF-16 with something else like `?` (a question mark, or like � that I see in the chrome)

I opened an issue in [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84693) and hope they fix it, but I'm looking for temporary solution